# How to move an item from one custom list to another custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have two custom lists (Timesheet and Weekly Timesheet). If any item exceeds the time length (or days) in the Timesheet list for more than 7 days then that item has to be copied (moved) to the Weekly Timesheet list.

I am working this scenario in SharePoint 2010 and SPD 2010.

Can anyone help me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality you can create a timer job that will check If any item exceeds the time length on daily basis.

Comment: Actually Iam trying to do this with Work flows in share point designer 2010..

Is it possible to do this scenario using WF through SPD 2010.